# How to get list of words from a list of lines in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If I have two lines, how can I split them into a list of two lists of words?
I tried the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = [Hello World, Welcome to StackOverFlow];
List<String> words;
List<List<String>> listOfWords;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            words = Arrays.asList(lines.get(i).split(" "));
            listOfWords = Arrays.asList(words);
        }
System.out.println(listOfWords);
```

The output of the above code is

[[welcome, to, StackOverFlow]]

Can someone please help me to get the output as follows?

[[Hello, World], [Welcome, to, StackOverFlow]]

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct, could you please add the code you run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every iteration of your for loop you are overwriting `listOfWords` by wrapping your latest `words` array in a new list. So effectively you will always just have your most recent line's list of words as the only item `listOfWords`.

To fix this modify following below the body of your `for` statement similar to the following:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] lines = {"Hello World", "Welcome to StackOverFlow"};
      List<String> words;
      List<List<String>> listOfWords = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // Must be instantiated or you will get NullPointerException

      for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          words = Arrays.asList(lines[i].split(" "));
          listOfWords.add(words); //Add to `listOfWords` instead of replace with a totally new one
      }

      System.out.println(listOfWords);
  }
```

Some of the syntax was not correct so I fixed it. In that process I converted `lines` into an Array. Tested and confirmed output.

Comment: Wow it works!!! I tried the same line `listOfWords.add(words);`, but didn't work. I might have had some other errors. Also, this works with `lines` as ArrayList. Thank you so much!!! I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out
        .println(splitStatementsIntoWords(new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("Hello World");
                add("Welcome to StackOverFlow");
            }
        }));

}

public static List<List<String>> splitStatementsIntoWords(List<String> statements) {

    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (statements != null) {
        for (String statement : statements) {
            result.add(Arrays.asList(statement.split("\\s+"))); // \\s+ matches one or more contigeous white space.
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```